# С Linux Передача в поток переменной

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность, pthread

Добрый день, проблема заключается в построении многопоточного вычисления и конкретно в том, что необходимый параметр **i** нужно передать в каждый поток из массива потоков размерности **n** на каждой итерации по **k**;

```
 //n = чему - то;
 int k;
 for(k= 0; k< K; k++)
 {
    pthread_t threads[n];
    double* res[n];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       struct info inft = {.parameter = i, .result = &res[i]}; // составление структуры для треда

       pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, calculate, (void*)&inft );
    }
    //ожидание закрытия треда и суммируем полученный резалт
    double result = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       pthread_join( threads[i], NULL);
       result += res[i];
    }
 }
```

функция для треда выглядит следующим образом:

```
void* calculate (void* args)
{
  struct info myinf = (struct info)&args;
  int i_current = myinf->parameter;

  printf("start with %d", i_current);

  double result = 0;
  result = somefunc(myinf->result, i_current);// что то делаем

  *(myinf->result)= result;
  printf("finish with %f", result);
}
```

Мной ожидалось что каждому потоку передастся свой **i** и для каждого поток будет разный результат.
Но в итоге на каждой итерации по **i** - в потоках одни и те же значения

> k = 1, n=3
>       start with 2
>       finish with 66666
>       start with 2
>       start with 2
>       finish with 66666
>       finish with 66666

я многое попробовал (локи, передача по ссылке и т.п.) но не работает как нужно. есть ли идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы фактически передаете указатель на локальную переменную. По выходе из цикла она вообще исчезает как таковая, так что в потоки передается адрес в никуда.
Вы же все равно выделяете память для каждого потока:

```
 pthread_t threads[n];
 double* res[n];
```

Ну так выделите тут же память и для передаваемых структур (кстати, если уж вы их создадите - то вам не понадобится передавать адрес для хранения результата - храните его прямо в структуре...). В данном случае все будет корректно - ваши потоки должны завершиться еще до выхода из блока, так что время жизни структур будет превышать время жизни потоков.

Только вот... `double*res[n]` - у вас есть массив указателей на `double`. Неинициализированный. Т.е. в структуре вы передаете адрес, по которому хранится указатель на `double`. Указатель неинициализированный. По которому вы что-то пишете. А потом, по выходу, вы начинаете суммировать **указатели**. Это точно та функциональность, которая вам нужна?...

Answer (score 1):

У вас при вызове pthread_create структура одна и та же, лежащая просто с стеке и во все потоки отдается адрес одной и той же области памяти. Надо явно выделять память под структуры, передаваемые внутрь потока, через malloc (или new), заполнять и передавать.

```
struct info *inft = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
inft->parameter=i;
...
pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, calculate, (void*)inft );
```

Только надо не забыть при завершении потоков выполнять free для этих областей памяти.

Comment: а как определять необходимое количество памяти? для malloc

Comment: @gebond вы же структуру выделяете, вот ее размер и берете. Как я и написал в примере `sizeof(struct info)`

Comment: Да незачем мучиться с `malloc` для такой мелочи. Я бы вообще создал `struct tinfo { pthread_t thread; int parametr; double res; } inft[n];` и не мучился. Далее в цикле записываем параметр, сохраняем поток, а на выходе и результат в структуре лежит. Все в одном месте, никаких `malloc/free` с опасностью что-то забыть и получить утечку...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы передаете потокам указатель на стековую переменную, адрес которой получается один и тот же. На самом деле это переменная создается при каждом вхождении в тело цикла, где вы стартуете потоки, и удаляется при выходе из него. Переданный адрес становится невалидным, но вы все равно продолжаете с ним работать из потоков.

Решение состоит в том, чтобы для каждого потока иметь свою отдельную структуру с которой другие потоки не работают.

```
int k;
for(k= 0; k< K; k++)
{
    pthread_t threads[n];
    struct info inft[n];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       inft[i].parameter = i;
       inft[i].result    = 0;  // теперь info.result должен быть не
                               // указателем, а просто int

       pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, calculate, (void*)&inft[i]);
    }
    // ...
}
```